# Display images in codeigniter with full_file path

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

I'am using codeigniter file upload class to upload images and save full_path in to the database.
But when displaying the images i can't see it.

Here is my code

```
<?php  foreach($images as $img) {?>
  <img src="<?php echo $img;?>" width="150">&nbsp;&nbsp;
<?php }?>
```

From view-source i will open the image link it will mixed with  `base-url` and image full_path.

> http://localhost/holiday/admin/profile/package_explained/C:/xampp/htdocs/holiday/uploads/package-images/img-holoday-sample.png

the value of `$img` is (ie fullpath of the image) `C:/xampp/htdocs/holiday/uploads/package-images/img-holoday-sample.png`.

How can i display image with full_path?

Comment: what `$img` prints??

Comment: `C:/xampp/htdocs/holiday/uploads/package-images/img-holoday-sample.png`

Comment: its wrong. Only get image name only form controller

Answer (score 1):

Only get image name form Controller. Do not track full path.

> > **Bcz your host server doesn't have path like this `C:/xampp/htdocs/`**

```
<?php  foreach($images as $img) 
{
    ?>
    <img src="<?php echo base_url()?>uploads/package-images/<?php echo $img;?>" width="150">&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <?php 
}
?>
```

Comment: @BlessanKurien only get image name form database

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you are not saving the path like that you have mentioned in DB:

**Try this (add http:// before print):**

```
<?php  foreach($images as $img) {?>
  <img src="http://<?php echo $img;?>" width="150">&nbsp;&nbsp;
<?php }?>
```